# GMap.NET で、地図の上にタイルで画像をオーバーレイ表示したい

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

[GMap.NET](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)を利用してWindowsFormsアプリケーションを作成しています。マップはOpenStreetMap利用しており地図の描画は出来ています。

その描画された地図の上に更にタイルでイメージをオーバーレイしたいのですが方法がわかりません。タイルでない画像をオーバレイすることは可能なのですが、ズームしたときに粗くなってしまうのでタイルで描画したいです。

Answer (score 1):

`GMapOverlay`クラスを継承してOnRenderをオーバーライドすれば自由に描画できるようです。動作確認はしていませんがこんな感じだと思います。

```
internal class CustomOverlay : GMapOverlay, IDisposable
{
    private Bitmap _Image;

    internal CustomOverlay(Bitmap image)
    {
        _Image = image;
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        using (var tb = new TextureBrush(_Image, WrapMode.Tile/*, TODO:イメージのサイズ指定*/))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(tb, Control.ClientRectangle); // TODO:位置指定
        }
     }

    // 以下IDisposableパターンの実装
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose();
        if (disposing)
        {
            using (_Image) { }
        }
        _Image = null;
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    ~CustomOverlay()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```